# C# entity framework using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a job interview tomorrow and they stated that i have an exam about "C# development using entity framework and LINQ".

For me, entity framework and LINQ are two new approaches. I already know to build C# application where i'd connect the app to a SQLServer database, using the normal connection strings and SQL syntax.

When researching about Entity framework, as a start i learned that i can use the SQLServer object explorer, and create a local database easily from visual studio, then add an OLE.net entity model and perform changes easily.
As an example, you can see the following code below used to insert a student in a student list.

```
  using (SchoolEntities1 context = new SchoolEntities1())
            {
                StudentList sl = new StudentList
                {
                    Name = tb_Name.Text,
                    Gender = cb_Gender.Text,
                    Grade = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Grade.Text)
                };
                context.StudentLists.Add(sl);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Is this the basic function of entity framework? Should i study anything else that might be useful (other than database manipulation INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT)?

Additionally for the LINQ, when researching about it, i see different types of coding as an example, is the definition of student list in the code above a LINQ function? Do i have to use lambda expressions in my codes?

Any links that can help me in  this small time frame would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The question behind your question is "what should I know in EF to do well in the interview". This is too broad and not a QA style question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 kinds of EF approaches.Those are:

1. Model First
2. Database First
3. Code First

Here you can find out basics of EF: [**Entity Framework Basics**](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)

There are 2 types of query methods.Those are:

**1. Query based**

*e.g : Projection*

```
IQueryable<Product> productsQuery = from product in context.Products
                                        select product;
```

**2. Method based**

*e.g : Projection*

```
 var query = context.Products
        .Select(product => new
        {
            ProductId = product.ProductID,
            ProductName = product.Name
        });
```

Here you can see this: [**Queries in LINQ to Entities**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can find out more at [**Entity Framework Interview Questions and Answers**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/676309/ADO-NET-Entity-Framework-Interview-Questions)

**Good Luck to you ! :)**

Answer (score 4):

For MVC as far as I know a basic crud Operation will be a good as a starter .That means Insert ,Update,Delete ,Details,Cascading dropdown list.But Besides you should gain knowledge about MVC routing clearly.

Currently you don't have any lambda expressions in your code.Basic Linq like list,count,joining etc you can learn in short time .

here is the data first approach 
[data first](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/2072a9/crud-operations-in-mvc/)

code first approach [code first](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

linq basic interview questions
[linq interview questions](http://www.dotnettricks.com/books/linq/interview)

And yes get some knowledge about relationship process.